# Why is scrapy FormRequest not working to login?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am attempting to login to https://ptab.uspto.gov/#/login via scrapy.FormRequest. Below is my code. When run in terminal, scrapy does not output the item and says it crawled 0 pages. What is wrong with my code that is not allowing the login to be successful?

```
import scrapy
from ..items import PatentItem
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class LoginNeedScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ptab'
    start_urls = ('https://ptab.uspto.gov/#/login')


    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                                formdata={'userName':'username', 'password':'password'},
                                                callback=self.logged_in)

    def logged_in(self, response):
        open_in_browser ( response )
        item = PatentItem()
        item['message'] = response.css('h1::text').extract()
        return item
```

Below is the output in terminal:

```
(Scrape) (base) Andrews-MacBook-Pro-5:patent rhodes259$ scrapy crawl ptab -o data.json
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: patent)
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08) - [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021), cryptography 3.4.6, Platform Darwin-19.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'patent',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'patent.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['patent.spiders']}
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 93dadadb5f6c58a8
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.006319,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 16, 5, 10, 2, 926018),
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 60981248,
 'memusage/startup': 60981248,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 16, 5, 10, 2, 919699)}
2021-03-16 01:10:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Have you gone to this web page and looked at the source code?  There are no `<form>` tags on that page.  Everything you see is constructed dynamically in Javascript.  If you aren't interpreting the Javascript, you won't see the form fields appear.  If you know what the fields are, you can send a POST request with the fields, but you won't be able to scrape them.

Comment: Would yo be able to suggest edits that would allow for a login to occur? Or are you saying that it is impossible to scrape via scrapy?

Comment: As I said, if you KNOW what the fields are on that form they build via Javascript, then you can create a request based on those fields as if you had clicked the "log in" button.  You don't need to scrape.

Comment: Yes, the POST request contained the 'userName' and 'password' payload. That is why I am unsure as to why it is not working. Perhaps there are hidden fields

Comment: `parse` is too late.  You need to apply your form fields BEFORE it fetches that page.  I think that means `start_requests`, but I don't know `scrapy` all that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST request when you click login is sent to https://ptab.uspto.gov/ptabe2e/rest/login